# React to toggling of menubar

Tags: java, macos, javafx, resize, menubar

I am currently writing a JavaFX application and I want to make the window react to the toggling of the system menubar. More specifically I want my app's topbar to move down and make space for it, while the menubar will currently just overlap the application window.

How I want it to be:
[image: How I want it to be:]
How it is:
[image: How it is:]

Comment: Are you looking for the [setUseSystemMenuBar](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/MenuBar.html#setUseSystemMenuBar%28boolean%29) method?

Comment: @VGR I tried using a JavaFX MenuBar and set useSystemMenuBarProperty to true. So if there is no trick that I don't know about then no.